# English subtitle of Extra Deutsch

Tags: resource

I am looking for English subtitles of [Extra Deutsch.](https://www.planet-schule.de/wissenspool/extra/inhalt/extra-deutsch.html) I have the German subtitles but I don't have the English subtitles. If anyone has an idea how to get them please share.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how it works.

Comment: Are there any reasons which make you assume, that there should be subtitles somewhere?

Comment: They made this tv series for teaching deutsch, and the german subtitle is available, so I thought if the purpose is to teach Deutsch then english subtitle might be available..

Comment: I don't think there are English subtitles. But using the "Filmskript" you should be able to translate the conversations by yourself

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the German language.

Comment: here you are: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZhSAffTLFQ&list=PL-TmF7dqLhIaAE2EnvnbtiSiLDYq1jOu8